# Inconsistent wire service cache refresh

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

I have a parent component with the following html structure:

**Parent.html**

```
<template>
  <template if:true>
    <lightning-tabset>
      <lightning-tab>
        <lightning-layout>
          <lightning-layout-item>
            <template>
            </template>
          </lightning-layout-item>
          <lightning-layout-item>
            <c-save-button></c-save-button>    <----
          </lightning-layout-item>
          <lightning-layout-item>
            <template if:true>
              <c-custom-combo-box needs-refresh={needsRefresh}></c-custom-combo-box>    <----
            </template>
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab>
        <lightning-layout>
          <lightning-layout-item>
            <c-custom-datatable needs-refresh={needsRefresh}></c-custom-datatable>    <----
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
      </lightning-tab>
    </lighting-tabset>
  </template>
</template>
```

The parent component and the table/combobox arrowed child components all have wire services provisioning data from an API (different but related endpoints). When a save button is clicked, I need to refresh the caches in all 3 places so that updated data is displayed. An event is passed up by the save button and handled in parent like below:

**Parent.js**

```
@track needsRefresh;

handleCancelClick(event){
    this.needsRefresh = false;
    this.disableComboBox = false;
    this.comboSelection = null;
    this.isTabsetDisplayed = false;
    this.resetpageData();
}

handleSaveClick(event){
    saveData({ jsonBody: JSON.stringify(this.pageData) })
    .then((response) => {
        this.needsRefresh = true;
        this.fireToast(response);
        refreshApex(this.officeResult);
        // use lwc:ref to call refresh method in c-custom-datatable
        // use lwc:ref to call refresh method in c-custom-combo-box
        this.handleCancelClick(event);
    });
}
```

Initially, I tried using lwc:refs to call a method in the child components that utilized refreshApex to update their caches, but this gave me extremely inconsistent behavior/didn't really work (I'm speculating it's because of the nested template structure?). So then I tried what's above, tracking a needsRefresh variable, then passing it to the child components via @api getters/setters that updated a @track variable like below:

**Child.js**

```
@track _needsRefresh;

@wire(getEvents, { countyId: '$countyid' })
mapEvents(result){
    this.eventResult = result;
    if (result.data){
        // do stuff with data
    }
}

@api
get needsRefresh(){
    return this._needsRefresh;
}
set needsRefresh(value){
    this._needsRefresh = value;
    refreshApex(this.eventResult);
}
```

It seems like the data is always one step behind, though, and I'm not really sure how to handle this. If I change data0 to data1, click save, then look at it again, it's still displaying data0. Then if I change the data1 to data2, save and look again, it's displaying data1. But I know the API is being updated every time because I've checked it in Postman in between updates. Could it be because of the if:true statements in the templates?

**Edit**

In `Parent.js` I changed `handleSaveClick()` to:

```
handleSaveClick(event){
    saveData({ jsonBody: JSON.stringify(this.pageData) })
    .then((response) => {
        this.needsRefresh = true;
        this.fireToast(response);
        refreshApex(this.officeResult);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        this.handleCancelClick(event);
    });
}
```

Because I thought maybe it needed more time to propagate down the change to `this.needsRefresh`, and now the `c-custom-combo-box` has the correct data every time, but `c-custom-datatable` has the correct data for a couple updates (seems to be exactly 3 save clicks, actually) then starts lagging one update behind again? Something is going on with when/how things are rendered I suspect. Might have to do with both `c-custom-combo-box` and `c-custom-datatable` being in a tabset, but the `c-custom-combo-box` is in the first (default) tab and `c-custom-datatable` is in the second tab and only rendered when you click on it, therefore is not receiving the changes to `this.needsRefresh` every time?

Comment: You didn't include any `lwc:ref` specifications in your markup example, so it's not entirely clear what you were expecting to happen. However, similar to how you can't apply this attribute to a `<template>` nor `<slot>`, I suspect you can't apply it to custom components. Especially if their outer tag is itself `<template>`.

Comment: Just for clarification in case somebody reads this in the future, in `c-custom-datatable` for example, I said `<c-custom-datatable lwc:ref="eventTable">`, defined a method in `c-custom-datatable`'s JS `handleRefresh()` that called `refreshApex(this.eventResult)`, then in `Parent.js`'s `handleSaveClick()` beneath `refreshApex(this.officeResult)` called `this.refs.eventTable.handleRefresh()`. Thank you for the reply though, that at least eliminates that option entirely for me.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications, rather than putting them in `Comments`.